# Set layout based on device's width in PIXELS

Tags: android

Is there a way I can set a layout to be displayed on devices which are at least 720 pixels wide?

Putting the layout file in a separate folder `layout-sw720px`, made it available only for devices with exactly 720 pixels.

Comment: I would expect that to be a build error, as AFAIK `px` is not a valid option there. You can use `dp` (e.g., `layout-sw720dp`), and that will work for that size or larger. `dp` is density-independent pixels, equivalent to CSS pixels, where 160dp = 1 inch. Using `px` for anything in Android app development is a major code smell, given the wide range of screen densities used with Android hardware.

Comment: I didn't build it, I was just checking which devices were available in the editor each time I changed the name of the folder. I don't have access to any device at the moment, and my laptop doesn't support emulation. So I hope `sw720dp` will work as you said :)

Comment: @CommonsWare According to [this](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-device-and-layout-mapping/) site, you seem to be mistaken.

Comment: There is nothing on that page that contradicts what I wrote.

Comment: `layout-sw720dp, screen with smallest width of 720dp, usually for tablets with screen of 10+ inches in diagonal measurement` is what you suggested. Pretty sure there are 5 inches phones that have 720 pixels in width. They still wouldn't be recognized as so.

Comment: "Pretty sure there are 5 inches phones that have 720 pixels in width" -- yes, but there are none that are 720dp in width. 720dp = 4.5", and that is not going to be the smallest width on a 5" diagonal screen. Again, `dp` in Android is density-independent pixels, equivalent to CSS pixels, where 160dp = 1 inch.